# Inject JavaScript call in React-Native WebView

Tags: react-native

I'd like to be able to inject a JavaScript call into a WebView within React-Native in order to be able to modify the view it is displaying.  For example, I'd like to inject:

```
 setRouteId(125123123);
```

and have it execute against the current context.  Is there a way to do this with React-Native's WebView?  I don't see anything currently in the source code but wanted to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I don't believe that it exists after a lot of investigation of the source code.  I put together a pull request to add support for stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in a pull request: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1191/files

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have control over the javascript you want to invoke, you can change the hash context of a url without the webview reloading. So if you set the webview url to append #route-id=125123123 to the current url, listening in JS for the onhashchange event will let you perform the action.